# Subtracting script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that counts down any number a user puts in.

```
Write-Host "$Value1"

[int]$Value1 - [int]1

do {
$outputString = read-host
$outputString - [int]1
}

until ($outputstring=0)
```

`$Value1` defines the number a user puts in. It seems to me that the initial value gets subtracted by 1, and after that the `$outputString` should take the read-host information and subtract 1 untill it reaches 0.
At this point in time the only output I get is the Write-Host "`[int]$Value1 - [int]1`", and the output subtracted by 1. However it does not loop untill it reaches 0.
Any way to fix this problem ?
Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
do {
    $outputString = read-host enter a number
} while ($outputstring -notmatch '^\d+$')

if($outputstring -gt 0)
{
    $outputstring..0 | ForEach-Object{
        $_
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually works perfect Shay! Thanks alot!
I am keen to figure out why it works however;
Would you mind explaining what the '^\d+$' does? And why does the ..0 invoke a counting down?

Either way thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
do {
$outputString = read-host
$outputString -= [int]1
}
until ($outputstring -eq 0)
```

**First**, the egal operator is `-eq` and not `=`

**Second**, you need to assign value to `$outputstring` if you want it to break the loop :

```
$outputString -= [int]1
$outputString = $outputString - [int]1
```